# How to have a difference in week units between two days (even if they're close but belong to different weeks)

Tags: r, date, difference

I make an example to be clear:

if we speak of 2006/2007, the last day of 2006 was Sunday and the first of 2007 was Monday.
According to Italy (but also other countries), they belong to different weeks.

How can I obtain this information in R?

If I do:

```
difftime(as.Date("2007-01-01"),as.Date("2006-12-31"),units="weeks")
```

I get: 0.1428571
...but I would like to know some way to get 1 (as they differ of 1 week)

Comment: +1 for posting your first question with a (truly) minimal reproducible example and what you have tried! Welcome to SO. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that Monday should be the first day of the week. R packages usually consider Sunday to be the first day of the week.

My solution uses the `lubridate` package and reduces the day of the week by one. With this Mondays become Sundays, the first day of the week for `lubridate`. I then use `floor_date` to get the first day of the week and `difftime` the result.

```
library(lubridate)
dates <-c(as.Date("2007-01-01"),as.Date("2006-12-31"))
weekdays(dates)
#[1] "Monday" "Sunday"
tempdates <-update(dates,wdays=wday(dates)-1)
weekdays(tempdates)
#[1] "Sunday"   "Saturday"
floor1 <-floor_date(tempdates, "week")
difftime(floor1[1],floor1[2], units = "weeks")
#Time difference of 1 weeks
```

January 1st and 2nd end up on the same week with this solution

```
dates <-c(as.Date("2007-01-02"),as.Date("2007-01-01"))
tempdates <-update(dates,wdays=wday(dates)-1)
floor1 <-floor_date(tempdates, "week")
difftime(floor1[1],floor1[2], units = "weeks")
#Time difference of 0 weeks
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments on my sloppy answer. And for providing a solution! +1!

Answer (score 0):

You could start with `strftime(as.Date("2007-01-01"),"%U")`, which identifies the week number in the year (look up `strftime`) and add the special case for the last week of a year maybe.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in "weeks" depends on whether you are using "week" as 7 days or as a sequence number. This gives you an R method for working with the second definition of "week":

```
 diff( c(as.numeric(format( as.Date("2007-01-01"), "%W")), 
        as.numeric(format(as.Date("2006-12-31"), "%W")) ))
 [1] 51
```